# What is the difference between signIn() vs acquireToken()?

Tags: android, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

In [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android), what is the difference between `signIn()` vs `acquireToken()`? Both are interactive, `signIn()` only works when the user is not already signed in - is that the only difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [its code](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/blob/dev/msal/src/main/java/com/microsoft/identity/client/SingleAccountPublicClientApplication.java#L244), internally `acquireToken` is called but unlike it, it is only meant to perform logins. Once logged in, it doesn't try again.

This is better suited just to authenticate into the application and no API calls are required (anything with token validation).